# Bidirectional OneToOne relation - Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

I have two models `(Slot, Appointment)`. On the appointment one, I have defined a `OneToOne` relation with the slot model, so good so far; thanks to the `RelatedManager` I can access the appointment from the slot object but this's done at python level and I need (for some future changes) `appointment_id` column to be created on the `Slot` table.

```py
class Slot(models.Model):
    start_at = models.DateTimeField()
    end_at = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = DateTimeRangeField(
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    # Bidirectional 
    appointment = models.OneToOneField(
        "appointments.Appointment",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="slot",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

class Appointment(models.Model):
    slot = models.OneToOneField(
        Slot,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="appointment",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

The code above will raise some errors when trying to create the migrations like:

```py
appointments.Appointment.slot: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'Appointment.slot' clashes with field name 'Slot.appointment'.
    HINT: Rename field 'Slot.appointment', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Appointment.slot'.
```

Basically, due to the python part of the ORM, you can't define the same field on both models.

Any idea of how to achieve this. I guess I will have to overwrite some parts of the `RelatedManager`. I could make this throw SQL but then it won't be clear on the code level.

Comment: All relations are bidirection (by default). There is no need to make two relations. Note that the related manager is *not* done at Python level. It will make a `JOIN` at the database level.

Comment: Umm got it but do you how can I get an `appointment_id` column on the `Slot` table. I currently trying to create an index for a `DateTimeRangeField` and need this for the range being unique for booked slots

Comment: If you're designing a database where you have a 1 to 1 relationship, consider storing that information in 1 table. For example, why not just have start, end, and duration in the `appointment` table? If you have a 1 to many relationship store a foreign key on the many side.

Comment: I need the slots beforehand to know the available time (also slots vary base on some settings and cannot be calculated on the fly) and that's why they're not on the appointment table

Comment: You can keep columns empty until they are ready to be filled in. Then you can have them on the appointment table.